# NoClassDefFoundError when using this code

Tags: java

I have copied this code from here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers#Java

```
package diningphilosophers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

enum PhilosopherState { Get, Eat, Pon }

class Fork {
    public static final int ON_TABLE = -1;
    static int instances = 0;
    public int id;
    public AtomicInteger holder = new AtomicInteger(ON_TABLE);

    Fork() { id = instances++; }
}

class Philosopher implements Runnable {
    static final int maxWaitMs = 100;                          //  must be > 0
    static AtomicInteger token = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static int instances = 0;
    static Random rand = new Random();
    AtomicBoolean end = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    int id;
    PhilosopherState state = PhilosopherState.Get;
    Fork left;
    Fork right;
    int timesEaten = 0;

    Philosopher() {
        id = instances++;
        left = Main.forks.get(id);
        right = Main.forks.get((id+1)%Main.philosopherCount);
    }

    void sleep() { try { Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(maxWaitMs)); }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {} }

    void waitForFork(Fork fork) {
        do {
            if (fork.holder.get() == Fork.ON_TABLE) {
                fork.holder.set(id);                //  my id shows I hold it
                return;
            } else {                                //  someone still holds it
                sleep();                            //  check again later
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    public void run() {
        do {
            if (state == PhilosopherState.Pon) {    //  all that pondering
                state = PhilosopherState.Get;       //  made me hungry
            } else { // ==PhilosopherState.Get
                if (token.get() == id) {            //  my turn now
                    waitForFork(left);
                    waitForFork(right);             //  Ah needs me some foahks!
                    token.set((id+2)% Main.philosopherCount);
                    state = PhilosopherState.Eat;
                    timesEaten++;
                    sleep();                        //  eat for a while
                    left.holder.set(Fork.ON_TABLE);
                    right.holder.set(Fork.ON_TABLE);
                    state = PhilosopherState.Pon;   //  ponder for a while
                    sleep();
                } else {                    //  token.get() != id, so not my turn
                    sleep();
                }
            }
        } while (!end.get());
    }
}

public class Main {
    static final int philosopherCount = 5; //  token +2 behavior good for odd #s
    static final int runSeconds = 15;
    static ArrayList<Fork> forks = new ArrayList<Fork>();
    static ArrayList<Philosopher> philosophers = new ArrayList<Philosopher>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < philosopherCount ; i++) forks.add(new Fork());
        for (int i = 0 ; i < philosopherCount ; i++)
            philosophers.add(new Philosopher());
        for (Philosopher p : philosophers) new Thread(p).start();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (runSeconds * 1000);

        do {                                                    //  print status
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("|");

            for (Philosopher p : philosophers) {
                sb.append(p.state.toString());
                sb.append("|");            //  This is a snapshot at a particular
            }                              //  instant.  Plenty happens between.

            sb.append("     |");

            for (Fork f : forks) {
                int holder = f.holder.get();
                sb.append(holder==-1?"   ":String.format("P%02d",holder));
                sb.append("|");
            }

            System.out.println(sb.toString());
            try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (Exception ex) {}
        } while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime);

        for (Philosopher p : philosophers) p.end.set(true);
        for (Philosopher p : philosophers)
            System.out.printf("P%02d: ate %,d times, %,d/sec\n",
                p.id, p.timesEaten, p.timesEaten/runSeconds);
    }
}
```

Compiling is okay. But on running, it gives `NoClassDefFoundError`. Why is that so? I have checked and found that the class names are okay. I even tried renaming them. But no use.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError which class? Are you using Main as running class? How you run it?

Comment: Sorry, it's for `Main` class

Comment: Do you run it with diningphilosophers.Main ?

Comment: Another homework... For Dining Philosophers I guess.

Comment: I just compiled it with `javac Main.java` and then ran it with `java Main`

Comment: why not do it in an ide

Comment: When compiling, the class files for all the classes are being generated. I can see that in the folder.

Comment: @MightyPork, just trying to understand the code and the working only. So didn't want to install a Java specific IDE for this.

Comment: @mostruash, thank you very much for the finding and for the down vote. Really "helped" me in figuring out the issue!!

Comment: @mostruash, no guess; it's the famous Dining Philosopher problem.

Comment: Copy/pasting code without understanding always leads to error.

Comment: Understanding how things are done without an IDE is never a bad idea.

Comment: @VppMan I did not down vote. I don't give a penny about your homework. But this is not good. Your friends are probably working on this problem too and they can find this solution. It can possibly lead to a disciplinary action because of plagiarism. Don't put the whole code on web.

Comment: @Rahul, there was no error or any other issues in the code. I did read the code before trying to compile and run. I didn't knew that the programs with packagename name has to be compiled and ran like what Ashaylnd mentioned in his answer. Anyway, thanks to Ashaylnd for the real help. And both of you guys could play with downvoting my question or you could talk more about copy/pasting.

Comment: BTW, I did mentioned that I copied and pasted from that page. Didn't claimed that it was my code! I would really appreciate if you guys try to post your suggestions or comments in clearing issues rather than making fun of the OP.

Comment: @mostruash, just now only saw your edit. Thanks for the advise. I appreciate suggestions/advises/hits, etc. But, it's not homework. I just wanted to test only. Because I was trying to recall my memory about the Philospher's problem.

Comment: What I quoted `Copy/pasting code ...` is a fact and always true. Again I didn't down vote; moreover I don't like down voting unless the question/answer really deserve down vote. No one making fun of you and neither people have much time for that. Question you asked, could easily be solved if you search google and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) make a directory called diningphilosophers

2) put your Main class there

3) one level up that directory, call:

```
javac diningphilosophers/Main.java
```

and then

```
java diningphilosophers.Main
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that this how we should compile and run those programs with package names.

Comment: @Ashalynd; Yes indeed it's nice and the problem is known as "Dining Philosopher". One of the classical problem/solution of OS Mutual exclusion issue.